# Does Maven plugin change the action of Run button (green triangle) in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I know Maven helps to build project, e.g. to create war. But in Eclipse which benefits does it add?

Does it add any magic when I press Run or only helps to get dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

It does not by default change the Run action.

But, as [illustrated in this article](https://github.com/RestComm/mediaserver/wiki/settingupdevenvformmscontributors#Setting_up_a_Maven_build_target_in_Eclipse), it adds to the Run configuration the possibility to define a "Run action", to trigger maven builds:

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/RestComm/mediaserver/images/EclipseMavenBuildTarget.png]

Comment: Thank you. And does it change the action of  "Run"->"Build project"?

Comment: And does Maven from Eclipse use the default Eclipse JRE or other JRE?

Comment: @Ekaterina It uses whatever JRE you define in the JRE tab (which should have the Eclipse one by default) Don't forget you can specify the java version you need in the pom.xml: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32207772/6309

Comment: @Ekaterina I missed your first comment "does it change the action of "`Run`"->"`Build project`"?": not quite: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14896212/6309. It supports Maven builds through a new "`Run as Maven build...`" interface.